# Problem with printing the words from a file where i stored them in a 2D array in C

Tags: arrays, c, file

i have a txt file like this :

```
                          AND e a b
                          NOT f c 
                          NOT d e f
```

I write a code that stores the words of the txt in a 2D array like that :

```
xw[0][0]=AND
xw[0][1]=e
xw[0][2]=a
xw[0][3]=b
xw[1][0]=NOT
xw[1][1]=f
xw[1][2]=c
xw[2][0]=NOT
xw[2][1]=d
xw[2][2]=e
xw[2][3]=f
```

, So right now i want to print the names (AND,NOT,AND) which are in the array , but when i do that  the output is not correct it seems that he reads the last line of the txt and always prints this name . Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<time.h>

#define SIZE 200

#define IN  3


struct element{

    char *name;

    int type;// timh pros to elementstable.

    double inputs[IN];

    int output;//index pros to singaltable.

};


//rand() % ( max - min ) ) + min; random times 
int main(){

    int wlenght=2,lines=0,size=22,len,ch1;
    FILE *fp;
    char c,filename[10], buf[200],*ptr;
    double **individual;
    struct element el;

    srand(time(NULL));

   
    printf("Enter number of inputs:");
    scanf("%d",&ch1);
    printf("Enter the file name you want to load :");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    //fgets(filename,100,stdin);
    

    fp=fopen(filename,"r");
    if(fp==NULL){
        printf("Could not load the file : %\n",filename);
        exit(1);
    }
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    char *check[SIZE][SIZE];
    while(fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),fp)!= NULL){
        puts(buf);
        ptr=strtok(buf," ");
        while(ptr!=NULL){ 
            check[i][j] = ptr;
            printf("xw[%d][%d]=%s\n",i,j,check[i][j]);
            ptr = strtok (NULL, " ");
            j++;
        }
        j=0;
        i++;
        lines++;
    }
    if(strcmp(check[0][0],"TLPINPUTS")==0){
        len=ch1+(lines-1);
    }else{
        len=ch1+lines;
    }
    
    printf("lines:%d\n",lines);
    rewind(fp);
    struct element elem[lines];
    double signalTable[len];
    char *elementTable[lines];
    for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(i<ch1){
            signalTable[i]=2.0;
            printf("%d)-%0.1f|\n",i,signalTable[i]);
        }
        else{ 
            signalTable[i]=0.0;
            printf("%d)-%0.1f|\n",i,signalTable[i]);
        }
        

    }
    int p=0;
    while(p<len){
        if(signalTable[p]==0.0){
            el.output=p;
            printf("H prwth kenh thesi gia na valei to output ths h pili einai sthn thesh :%d\n",el.output);
            break;
        }
        p++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<lines;i++){
        printf("%s\n",check[i][0]);
    }
    /*
    for(int i=0;i<lines;i++){
        elem[i].name=check[i][0];
        printf("check[%d][0]=%s\n",i,check[i][0]);
        elem[i].type=i;
        elem[i].output=el.output;
        el.output++;
        elementTable[i]=elem[i].name;
        if(strcmp(elem[i].name,"TLPINPUTS")==0){
            continue;
        }
        
    }
    for(int i=0;i<lines;i++){
        printf("(%d)-%s |\n",i,elementTable[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<lines;i++){
        printf("elem:%d: onoma:%s , type:%d(array) , output:%d(signalTables)\n",i,elem[i].name,elem[i].type,elem[i].output);
    }
*/
    
    
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

when i run this code am getting this output :

```
NOT
NOT
NOT
```

, if change the last line of the txt to AND it will print AND everywhere besides that when i check the array of words it seems right .For example,this is the words where my code fill in the array:

```
AND e a b
xw[0][0]=AND
xw[0][1]=e
xw[0][2]=a
xw[0][3]=b
NOT f c
xw[1][0]=NOT
xw[1][1]=f
xw[1][2]=c
NOT d e f
xw[2][0]=NOT
xw[2][1]=d
xw[2][2]=e
xw[2][3]=f
```

, i dont know what to do ! please help

Comment: `check[i][j] = ptr;` That's just setting every entry to point to somewhere in the **same buffer**. That buffer gets overwritten on every loop. So of course the result is only the last thing written into the buffer. You need to make new copies of the data. One option is to use `strdup`.

Comment: @kaylum could you please give me an example for that ?

Comment: `check[i][j] = strdup(ptr)`. And need to `free` all the `check` entries when they are no longer needed.

Comment: @kaylum thank you very mutch it works !

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s",filename);` and 
    
    `//fgets(filename,100,stdin);`   The array `filename` is only 10 bytes long.  so the call to `scanf()` should be:  `scanf("%9s",filename);`  The call to `fgets()` would seriously overrun the `filename` buffer, resulting in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event.